# How can I search a value from a df inside another df?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I try to search a value from a df inside another df, I will explain it as a table it will be more talking.

```
df (comment columns is for better comprehension and is not necessary)
```

https://pastebin.com/Ch1S5eaz .csv link

| CP | Libellé | No Tiers SAP | OS | OS cor (empty at the beginning) | flag | (COMMENT) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 105 | JFEZ 0090280164 koad ZE-83 |  | LP28 | LP30 | flag | we take 0090280164 and search it inside df_full (containing the same columns) and we get the OS from it and put it inside the "OS cor" of the 2 flagged lines. |
| 380 | not important because not flagged |  | DO20 |  |  | we don't do anything |
| 209 | not important because not flagged |  | OE29 |  |  | we don't do anything |
| -105 | JFEZ 0090280164 koad ZE-83 |  | LP29 | LP30 | flag | we take 0090280164 and search it inside df_full (containing the same columns) and we get the OS from it and put it inside the "OS cor" of the 2 flagged lines. |
| 15 | not important because OS is the same |  | DO10 |  | flag | we don't do anything |
| -15 | not important because OS is the same |  | DO10 |  | flag | we don't do anything |
| -19 | everything but 10 numbers | 0001008579 | BO29 | DK29 | flag | we search the No Tiers SAP inside df_full to search inside every lines containing this No Tiers SAP and we take the one with the same abs CP and take the OS and put it in OS cor |
| 19 | everything but 10 numbers | 0001008579 | SA20 | DK29 | flag | we search the No Tiers SAP inside df_full to search inside every lines containing this No Tiers SAP and we take the one with the same abs CP and take the OS and put it in OS cor |

```
df_full
```

https://pastebin.com/QdrTZkBX .csv link

| CP | No Piece FI | No Tiers SAP | OS | (COMMENT) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 105 | 0090280164 |  | LP30 | we search 0090280164 from the "Libellé" inside No Piece FI to take OS, we take this one because CP is the same |
| 209 | 0090280164 |  | DA20 | we don't take this one because CP is not the same as the base line. |
| 19 |  | 0001008579 | DK29 | Same CP so we take that OS |
| 25 |  | 0001008579 | DK80 | Not same CP |

In the case that the 2 lines flagged inside df have something inside Libellé, and the 2 found a line from it inside df_full with an OS then we took the one that has the same CP as the absolute value.

There is also some case were there is no Libellé, so we search from No Tiers SAP the same CP and get the OS.

How can I do that ?
I tried this :

```
tmp = (
 df.assign(sign=np.sign(df['CP']),
           n=df.groupby(['Centre de profit  (4car)', 'CP']).cumcount(),
           abs=df['CP'].abs()
          ).reset_index()
   .pivot(index=['Centre de profit  (4car)', 'abs', 'n'], columns='sign', values='index')
)

keep = tmp.where(tmp.notna().all(axis=1)).stack().values

df.loc[keep, 'flag'] = 'flag'

df['os cor'] = False
for _, group in df[df['flag'] == 'flag'].groupby(['Centre de profit  (4car)', df['CP'].abs()]):
    print(group)
    if group['Ordre statistique'].nunique() > 1 or group['Nature comptable (8 car.)'].nunique() > 1:
        for i in range(len(group)):
            libelle_poste = group.iloc[i]["Libellé Poste"]
            match = re.search(r'(^|\s)\d{8}(\s|$)', libelle_poste)
            if match:
                num = match.group()
                df_temp = df_full[df_full["No Piece FI"] == num]
                if not df_temp.empty:
                    if df_temp.iloc[0]["CP"] == group.iloc[i]["CP"]:
                        os_value = df_temp.iloc[0]["Ordre statistique"]
                        df.loc[group.index, "os cor"] = df.loc[group.index, "os cor"] | (group["Ordre statistique"] != os_value)
                        df.loc[(group["Ordre statistique"] != os_value) & (df["No Piece FI"].isin(nums)), "os cor"] = True
```

but didn't get any result.
Thanks you !

Comment: I don't really get the logic, nor the difference between the two dataframes. Also, please provide their constructors for easier reproducibility

Comment: You say *"we take 0090280164 and search it inside the base df (containing the same columns) and we get the OS from it and put it inside the "OS cor" of the 2 flagged lines."* What is the `base df`? Is it necessary to strip out just this `009028014` value from the string? Is the pattern always the same to find this value in the string? What column in the "base df" do we "search"? To me this sounds like **1)** apply some regex to get those numeric values from the string first **2)** use merge to join the two dataframes and find your results. But that's a guess as your requirements aren't clear.

Comment: I've made an edit, it was for df_full. Yes the pattern is the same it's a regex, as I put inside my code. I want to basically take "0090280164" from df "Intitulé" to search it inside "No Piece FI" of df_full, if it find something then take the OS from df_full and put it inside OS from df of corresponding lines.

Comment: The excepted output is the first table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complicating things unnecessarily. Just map a function to extract the values you need.

Consider:

```
def extractor(value):
    m_search r'_(d{8})w*' 
    try:
        return re.match(m_search,value).group(1) #Index of your group?
    except:
        return None

df["No Piece FI"] = df["Libelle"].map(extractor) #now creates a new column on df.
```

The above code snippet could then be used again to generate a new column with the values from your second df...or you could just merge your dfs.